# Active Record Model Validation if email is blank or empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-validation

In `sign up` page I want to validate user's email if user enter invalid email or email textbox left blank and want to show error message `Enter your email address`

My `User` Model:

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness:  { case_sensitive: false }
```

With the above regex, I am validating email but do not know how to add and display error meesage.

Kindly help me. Thanks.

Comment: How to add error?I didn't get that.You mean Error message?

Answer (score 2):

Just try:

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, 
          :presence => {:message => "Enter your email address!" },
          :format => { :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX, :message => "Enter a valid Email address !"}
          :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false, :message => "Email already exists!"}
```

To view these error, use the default error helper provided by Rails (`<%= f.error_messages %>` ).

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => {:controller=>"users", :action => "sign_up" } do |f| %>  
   <%= f.error_messages %> 
   ---form fields and contents --
<%end%>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @user3463868: Updated answer. Please use error helper and if it really helps you, accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the Error Message,you can simply add `message: 'your message'`Just do like this.

If you want to provide a separate Error Messages,then you have to split the validations.

```
validates :email, presence: true, :format=> { :with=> VALID_EMAIL_REGEX , :message=> 'Enter your Email Address' }

validates :email, uniqueness: {:case_sensitive => false, :message => 'Please provide a valid Email' }
```

Comment: but it give me error "Unknown validator: 'MessageValidator'" at this line "validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, message: 'Enter your Email Address'"

Comment: @user3463868 Which Rails version are you using?